# Request URI too long on spartacus services

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I've been trying to make use of `service.getNavigation()` method, but apparently the Request URI is too long which causes this error:

```
Request-URI Too Long

The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
```

Is there a spartacus config that can resolve this issue?
Or is this supposed to be handled in the cloud (ccv2) config?

Comment: Related GitHub ticket: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/6406

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which service are you talking about specifically and what data are you passing there. For starters, please read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414

Additionally it would benefit everyone if you could say something about the service you're using and the data you are trying to pass/get.

Comment: we're using the `service.getNavigation()` method to access the `CategoryNavigationComponent`. Our Categories are too many, and maybe that's why it exceeds the limit.. 

Also, our project uses CCV2. So can this be resolved in the cloud config?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation component is firing a request for all componentIds. If you have a navigation with a lot of (root?) elements, the maximum length of HTTP GET request might be too long for the given client or server.

The initial implementation of loading components was actually done by a POST request, but the impression was that we would not need to support requests with so many components. I guess we were wrong.

Luckily, the legacy POST based request is still in the code base, it's `OccCmsComponentAdapter.findComponentsByIdsLegacy`.

The easiest way for you to use this code, is to provide a `CustomOccCmsComponentAdapter`, that extends from `OccCmsComponentAdapter`. Then you can override the `findComponentsByIds` method and simply call the `super.findComponentsByIdsLegacy` and pass in a copy of the arguments.

A more cleaner way would be to override the `CmsComponentConnector` and directly delegate the load to the `adapter.findComponentsByIdsLegacy`. I would not start here, as it's more complicated. Do a POC with the first suggested approach.

Comment: Thanks, for this.. But I got stuck on the part where I need to cast the type from `Observable<CmsComponent[]>` to an `Observable<NavigationNode>`  

  
Any ideas on how to?

Comment: **we still want to make use of the `cx-navigation-ui` selector to translate and dynamically get the url links of the category navigation.