# Workaround of the problem of too big GET request when getting cms components

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

After updating our backend with fairly massive category tree we ended up with ~600 components in total in one request and our `GET` is basically too big.

I know there is related question:
[Request URI too long on spartacus services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000422/request-uri-too-long-on-spartacus-services)
and github issue:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/6406
but we don't want to use `POST` instead of `GET` to get the cms components.

Actually, so far we're trying the approach of splitting the big call to the visible part of the navigation and the rest. Spartacus will load nested subnav components in subsequential calls triggered by user action (click, tap). This has additional advantage: kind of lazy loading of the big navigation tree. However the problem is still there during the SSR. We believe no backend changes are required.

I know there are also pagination feature on the backend but not sure how it can be used here (without destroying lots of Spartacus logic for getting the cms components).

Another option we had on the plate was getting the whole menu tree as a `JSON` from the backend but this also needs a custom solution on both frontend and backend.

So the question is: are there any other cases of that problem already solved?

I know it's a common problem and one day Spartacus team might provide a solution to it but as for now it would be nice if we have the list of possible solutions so anyone can benefit from it while tackling it's own case caused by the main issue (Spartacus' combining multiple request for cms components into one call, which is good obviously, for most cases :)).

Comment: The only way i could think of is splitting this into multiple requests

Comment: You can try to create a custom `CmsComponentConnector` to replace the one in core lib.
In `CmsComponentConnector`, there is a function `getList`. It calls `CmsComponentAdapter.findComponentsByIds`, which gets all components in one request. 
In your custom `CmsComponentConnector`, you can use `OccCmsComponentAdapter.findComponentsByIds`, in which you can pass pagination data (e.g. currentPage, pageSize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any existing solutions to this problem at the moment. The simples possible workaround would be overriding OccCmsComponentAdapter and replacing one request with two if needed (under the hood) or at bit higher level (CmsComponentConnector).

Otherwise. it's a good candidate for a new issue [Spartacus github repo](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=) as it might not only speed up the proper fix but also can result in some workarounds being tested.

Comment: Thanks @dunqan, will create a ticket shortly :)

Comment: Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/12439)